# Testing Vue with Jest: custom event handled by parent, emitted by child component

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a set of parent & child vue components. The child emits an event that the parent handles. I'd like to test that it handles the custom event correctly, but I am stuck.

Parent.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <!-- phonebook -->
    <ChildComponent
      class="row mt-4"
      @customEvent="val => customEventHandler(val)"
    ></ChildComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      ChildComponent,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        test: [1, 2, 3, 4]
      };
    },
    methods: {
      customEventHandler(id) {
        // removes item `id` from the `test` array
        this.test = this.test.filter((item) => item !== id);
      },
    }
  };
</script>
```

This is one thing I've tried:

Parent.spec.js

```
import { mount, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import  Parent from '../../src/Parent.vue';
import  ChildComponent from '../../src/components/ChildComponent.vue';

describe('customEvent event', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    parent = mount(Parent, {
      data() {
        return {
          test: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        };
      },
    });
  });

  it('should trigger the customEventHandler method', async() => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(parent.vm, 'customEventHandler');
    await parent.findComponent(ChildComponent).trigger('customEvent', 2);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

The test above fails and I'm not sure why.

I've also tried the following tests:

```
// check what the spy has been called with 
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);

// test the side-effects of the `customEventHandler` method
expect(parent.vm.test.length).toEqual(3)
```

These also fail - it's as though the event isn't being triggered at all (is that it?), or I'm trying to test something that isn't possible.

Is there an accepted way to test a parent component's handling of an event emitted by a child component?

Answer (score 6):

#### Triggering events

[`trigger()`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#trigger) only works for native DOM events. For custom events, use [`wrapper.vm.$emit()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) (and no need to `await` it):

```js
// await parent.findComponent(ChildComponent).trigger('customEvent', 2);
//                                            ^^^^^^^ ❌

parent.findComponent(ChildComponent).vm.$emit('customEvent', 2);
```

#### Spying on methods

Vue 2 does not support spying on methods from the `wrapper.vm` instance, so the spying needs to be done on the *component definition* (`Parent.methods`) **before mounting**:

```js
// const spy = jest.spyOn(parent.vm, 'customEventHandler');
//                        ^^^^^^^^^ ❌ not supported in Vue 2

const spy = jest.spyOn(Parent.methods, 'customEventHandler')
const parent = mount(Parent)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-jest-spy-on-methods?file=tests%2Funit%2FParent.spec.js)

Note that Vue 3 *does* support spying via `wrapper.vm`.

Comment: @paddotk I've updated the answer with a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-jest-spy-on-methods?file=tests%2Funit%2FParent.spec.js) that shows spying on `Parent.methods` in Vue 2 works. And here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-jest-spy-on-methods-l3dgpn?file=tests%2Funit%2FParent.spec.js) that shows spying on `parent.vm` does **not** work in Vue 2. Can you share a link that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: Ah yeah indeed. Quite strange, because in my Vue2 project it doesn't work (Jest says `Cannot spy on a primitive value`). Maybe it's because of Typescript or the way I define components: `export default Vue.extend<IData, any, any>({`

Comment: @paddotk Can you share a link to an example where spying on `parent.vm` methods works in Vue 2? How did that work for you?

Comment: It's strange, looking up `jest.spyOn` yields no results in the docs at all, merely in questions/issues on Github etc. [Here](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/issues/775) is an example. To my knowledge, this is the way to do it and it's the way I've always done it. PS I'm using Vue Test Utils v1.0.3 in case that matters.